# wamp server not working after my pc got shutdown unexpectedly EparseError

Tags: wamp, wamp-protocol

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsY3v.jpg)

my pc got shutdown suddenly and when I reopen  wamp showing this error

My wampmanager.ini
[BigMenu]

BigKey0=NC,0,0

[TextMenu]

TextKey0=NC,0,8,$000ff9f2,$00D77800,NC,NC

[TextMenuColor]

TextKeyColor0=NC,$000ff9f2,$000ff9f2,$000ff9f2,0

[LeftSeparatorMenuColor]

LeftSeparatorKeyColor0=NC,$000ff9f2,$000ff9f2,$000ff9f2,0,Arial,8

[RightSeparatorMenuColor]

RightSeparatorKeyColor0=NC,$000ff9f2,$000ff9f2,$000ff9f2,0,Arial,8

[PromptCustom]

PromptKey0=Default,10,$00FCFDFE,$00000000,$00FCFDFE,$00000000

PromptKey1=NC,10,$00F0F0F0,$00000000,$00FCFDFE,$00000000

[ScreenWaitMessage]

TitleApplication=AeTrayMenu

ServicesStatus1=Start Services

ServicesStatus2=Services Started

WaitMessage1=To Be Patient !

WaitMessage2=Ready !

WaitMessage3=Warning !

WaitRestartReadConfig=Update settings !

LongProcessing=0

LongProcessingScreen=0

[Timer]

NumberStart=3

CountStart=2

[Options]

AeTrayMode=64 Bits

AeTrayOldMode=64bit

AeTrayVersion=3.2.4.9

I have tried php refresh.php in script folder

I have tried php refresh.php in script folder